# How are perforce stream depots mapped to the backend

Tags: perforce

When we search the Linux box hosting perforce I only see normal depots. What's the mapping from the front end to the backend for stream depots please?

i.e. In the p4 client I see depot, main, and mynewstream.

In linux I see, var/perforce/depot and var/perforce/main but no streamdepots.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as for any other depot.  Run `p4 depot -o DEPOTNAME` and look at the `Map:` field -- that tells you the directory where the archives are stored on the back end.  It defaults to `DEPOTNAME/...` (relative to `P4ROOT`) but can also be an absolute path pointing to any writable filesystem.

Note that if a depot only includes files that are branched or copied from other depots, there are no physical back end copies (the database "lazy copies" them by reference from archives in other depots).  If you've just seeded your stream depot by branching from another depot and haven't made any edits to it, that'd explain why you don't see a directory for it on the back end.